# How can I print from (whatever user input integer) to 0 and then back to the integer without using recursion? (Computing class assignment)

Tags: c

My professor wants use to ONLY use while loops and call 2 different functions, which I have done. I am really stuck on how to tweak this so that if I put in, say, 16, that it will list 16 to 0 on separate lines, as well as 0 to 16 again on separate lines. I can do this with recursion very well for some reason, but without being able to do that, I am lost on how to make this work. 
My computing class is learning with C language, so that is what my code is written in.We are also not required to validate input and are under the assumption that the user is entering valid input (a positive integer). Any tips are well appreciated! Thank you.

---

```
          #include <stdio.h>

       void loop_down_to_zero(int number);
       void loop_up_to_int(int number);

      int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
      printf("please enter a positive integer:");
      int number;
      number = ("%d" >= 0);
      loop_down_to_zero(number);
      loop_up_to_int(number);
      scanf("%d", &number);
      printf("****\n");

      return 0;
    }

     void loop_down_to_zero(int number)
     {
      while ( number > 0 )
     {
        loop_down_to_zero(number - 1);
        printf("\n%d", number-1);

     }

     }

    void loop_up_to_int(int number)
   {
    while ( number >= 0 )
   {
      loop_up_to_int(number+ 1);
      printf("%d\n", number+1);
    } 
     return;
     }
```

Comment: This is not C `number = ("%d" >= 0);`, at least not any meaningful C.

Comment: Also your number is positive and you're incrementing it so, ```while ( number >= 0 )``` doesnt make any sense

Comment: @arvind If you also make an answer from your comment, the two answers could peacefully live together and both be appreciated. I did not want to use your good input in mine.

Comment: @Yunnosch Its alright, im fine as long as OP is getting answers

Comment: @arvind Thanks, I quote you now, to make sure it does not get lost. There is however still room for a second answer elaborating on a solution proposal, instead of only pointing out the problem. I only added the very first hint on what you spotted. Go on, harvest some well-earned reputation. (But, in my opinion, better refrain from giving a complete solution.)

Comment: If you read `number` input by the user and then loop from `number` while the loop variable is `>= 0` that provides a descending output, and what if you then loop in the ascending direction?

Answer (score 2):

This is not C

```
number = ("%d" >= 0);
```

At least not any meaningful C.

Replace it by the actual input-reading a few lines later,

```
scanf("%d", &number);
```

So that you have a meaningful `number` for the calls to the functions.

That should solve you immediate blocking point.
Then have a look at the hint at your next problem, provided as a comment by arvind:
"Also your number is positive and you're incrementing it so, `while ( number >= 0 )` doesn't make any sense." You probably want something including `(current_number <= number)`.
Then for a recursion solutin use `if` instead of `while`.
Then to get you started on a non-recursive solution, actually change within the loop body the variable you are testing inside the loop condition;
otherwise you have a guaranteed endless loop killing your programs functionality.

(*I intentionally do not give a complete solution, according to the compromise described here, [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) The asker-side of which OP has well honored in my opinon.*)

Comment: Hello everyone, thank you so much for all of the feedback! I greatly appreciate it. I actually went to my professors office hours today and he was able to explain where I was going wrong and why, so I no longer need assistance with this problem. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Please create an answer with what your teacher explained. I would be interested. I would especially be interested whether they contradict this answer.